# Using Python Client for AI Platform (Unified) in Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to "wrap" Google Python Client for AI Platform (Unified) into a Cloud Function.

```
import json
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value

def infer(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()

    project="simple-1234"
    endpoint_id="7106293183897665536"
    location="europe-west4"

    api_endpoint = "europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com"

    # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = aiplatform.gapic.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    # for more info on the instance schema, please use get_model_sample.py
    # and look at the yaml found in instance_schema_uri

    endpoint = client.endpoint_path(
        project=project, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id
    )

    instance = request.json["instances"]
    instances = [instance]

    parameters_dict = {}
    parameters = json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())
    
    try:
        response = client.predict(endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters)
        if 'error' in response:
            return (json.dumps({"msg": 'Error during prediction'}), 500)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception when calling predict: ", e)
        return (json.dumps({"msg": 'Exception when calling predict'}), 500)
    
    print(" deployed_model_id:", response.deployed_model_id)
    # See gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/predict/prediction/tables_classification.yaml for the format of the predictions.
    predictions = response.predictions
    for prediction in predictions:
        print(" prediction:", dict(prediction))
    return (json.dumps({"prediction": response['predictions']}), 200)
```

When calling `client.predict()` I'm getting exception `400`

```
{"error": "Required property Values is not found"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `parameters` variable is not correct, in the [documentation example](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-automl#aiplatform_predict_image_classification_sample-python) that variable is set like this, as an example:

```py
parameters = predict.params.ImageClassificationPredictionParams(
                 confidence_threshold=0.5, max_predictions=5,
             ).to_value()
```

This is probably why the error says the properties are not found. You will have to set your own parameters and then call the predict method.